# Include specific classes in jar archive in gradle build

Tags: java, gradle

I have a newbie question on a gradle java project. I wish to configure the output artifact jar of this to only include certain classes from my project. I have the desired classes to be included in a file say `classes.txt` that is generated as a part of a separate task. How should one configure the `jar` task of the gradle build so that does this. This is what I have tried so far:

```
jar {
    // reset actions
    actions = []
    copy {
        def dependentClasses = file("classes.txt")
        if (dependentClasses.exists()) {
            dependentClasses.eachLine { include it }
        }

        from sourceSets.main.output
        includeEmptyDirs = false
        into "build/tmp/jar" //Some temporary location
    }
    // How to zip the contents?
}
```

I am sorry for the possibly naive question, but I haven't had luck with the other solutions seen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Opal's answer, here is the answer for the include of files

```
apply plugin: 'java'

jar {
   def included = project.file('classes.txt').readLines()
   include { f ->
      included.any { i -> f.isDirectory() ? true : f.path.replaceAll(File.separator, '.').contains(i) }
   }
}
```

The slight trick was that the `FileTreeElement` `f` being passed to the closure also has the package directory passed and if that happens to return false, the subtree below is not traversed and hence the check on it being a directory to return true to enable processing of the subtree.

Demo for solution is [here](https://github.com/kilokahn/stackoverflow/tree/master/32081741) and Lol1.class will be included. Thanks for the help, Opal!

Answer (score 3):

It can be done in the following way:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

jar {
   def excluded = project.file('classes.txt').readLines()

   exclude { f ->
      excluded.any { e -> f.path.replaceAll(File.separator, '.').contains(e) }
   }
}
```

Demo can be found [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/32081741), `Lol1.class` will be excluded.

Comment: Thanks @Opal - I was looking for including specific classes rather than excluding, but I am guessing the solution should be similar - will try it out and let you know. However, if you know the solution off the top of you head, you can edit it here itself? BTW, loved the systematic github code demo organization!

Comment: Unfortunately not. Including does not handle single files but groups or patterns. Github demo isn't systematic ;]

Comment: Can you please post/edit the code to match on patterns? I am guessing if we pass specific patterns that correspond to each class, we can achieve the same effect? Apologies if I am completely off with my understanding here...